# При авторизации в Google из Chromium в приложении на Delphi 10.3 YouTube выдаёт ошибку о использовании небезопасного браузера. Как авторизоваться?

Tags: javascript, delphi, chromium, google-account

При попытке авторизации в сервисах Google с использованием браузера Chromium свежей версии встроенного в приложение которое написано на Delphi 10.3 вижу сообщение о том что используется небезопасный браузер или приложение, привожу полный текст того что пишет Google:

На русском языке:

> Не удалось войти в аккаунт
> Возможно, этот браузер или приложение небезопасны. Подробнее…
> Попробуйте сменить браузер. Если вы уже используете поддерживаемый браузер, обновите страницу и попробуйте войти ещё раз.

На английском языке:

> Couldn't sign you in
> This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
> Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

[image: Скринсшот проблемы авторизации в Google из Chromium]

Подумал что у Chromium какой то свой User-Agent по которому сервер Google или JavaScript в браузере определяет браузер и выдаёт указанное сообщение о ошибке, вот только проанализировав User-Agent вижу что он не отличается от того который использует Chrome и версия его такая же как сейчас использует обновлённый до последней версии Chrome(в моём случаи это 87.0.4280.88). На всякий случай проверил, может JavaScript как то идентифицирует браузер как Chromium, вызов alert(navigator.userAgent) в JavaScript дал полное соответствие User Agent тому что приходит на сервер.

Вопрос, как обойти проблему и всё же производить авторизацию из приложения написанного на Delphi 10.3 и использующего Chromium в сервисах Google, как минимум в YouTube и Gmail?
И каким образом Google определяет небезопасный браузер, то есть что там за алгоритм и в особенности на какой параметр он реагирует, что появляется такая ошибка, при том что User-Agent не отличается от того что использует современный обновлённый Chrome?

Comment: Уже после того как задал вопрос, подумал, а что если я этот User-Agent которым подписывается Chromium засуну в Firefox(на текущий момент это 84-ая версия). Проверил на своём сайте, Firefox теперь говорит что он: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 вычистил куки, попробовал залогиниться в YouTube - никаких проблем - авторизовался. Прихожу к выводу что User-Agent в этой ситуации не при делах, и либо Chromium как то иначе обрабатывает JavaScript или Google специально сделали чтобы из Chromium нельзя было авторизоваться.

Comment: Вот тут пишут, что это связано с запуском хрома в дебаг-режиме: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673634

Answer (score 1):

С похожей проблемой столкнулся, как понимаю началось это перед новым годом.

Изменение User-Agent ничего не дает, пока предположение, что это как-то связано с библиотеками последних версиях Chromium или даже с сертификатом безопасности.

Я когда поверх библиотеки заменяю, то Яндекс страницу открывает, а Google падает с ошибкой.

Если скачать последнею версию Chromium браузера, там страница ввода пароля открывается.